# Find intersection points between ParametricRegion and other curves

Tags: graphics, regions, parametric-functions, intersection

How do you instruct Mathematica to return intersection points between curves as numerical values, when using `ParametricRegion` to represent at least one of the curves? For example, these are the regions for a line segment and a cubic Bezier curve:

```
cubicbez[a_, b_, c_, d_, t_] := (1 - t)^3*a + 3*(1 - t)^2*t*b + 3*(1 - t)*t^2*c + t^3*d

bezierRegion[{a_,b_,c_,d_}]:=ParametricRegion[cubicbez[a,b,c,d,t],{{t,0,1}}]

r1=Line[{{2,1},{4,7}}];
r2=bezierRegion[{{0,5},{9,6},{-2,4},{6,3}}];
ri=RegionIntersection[r1,r2];

Show[{Region[r1],Region[r2],Region[ri,BaseStyle->Red]},Frame->True]
```

[image: Regions r1, r2 and ri]

As you can see, Mathematica has no trouble finding the intersection points.

I then ask Mathematica to return the coordinates of the intersection points as follows:

```
MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[ri]]
```

which returns

> {{3.20154, 4.60463}, {3.42285, 5.26855}}

when using Mathematica 12.3.0.0. I.e., one of the intersections points (the lower left one) is missing.

What would be the proper way to get the intersection points?

(N.B. I know that you can compute the intersections of a cubic Bezier curve and a line in other ways, e.g. algebraically using Cardano's formula, or using numerical methods, but I'd like to know how to use Mathematica's regions for that purpose.)

Comment: `MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[ri, CoordinateBounds[ri]]]` gives all three points.

Comment: With version 12.3 one can do: `DiscretizeRegion[ri, CoordinateBounds[ri]] // MeshCoordinates` or `Solve[{x, y} \[Element] r1 && {x, y} \[Element] r2, {x, y}] // N`.

Comment: Version 11.2 give me correct result with same code {{2.95674, 3.87023}, {3.20154, 4.60463}, {3.42285, 5.26855}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the two-argument form of `DiscretizeRegion` we get three points:

```
MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[ri, CoordinateBounds[ri]]]
```

> ```
>  {{2.95674, 3.87023}, {3.20154, 4.60463}, {3.42285, 5.26855}}
> ```

FWIW, we can also use `MeshPrimitives` to get the three `Point`s:

```
MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@ri, 0]
```

> ```
> {Point[{2.95674, 3.87023}], Point[{3.20154, 4.60463}], Point[{3.42285, 5.26855}]}
> ```

Comment: The expression `MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@ri, 0]` yields only the latter two points for me. Maybe its a bug in Mathematica 12.3.0.0 ... . The option `CoordinateBounds[ri]`, however, works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `RegionMember` and `Solve` or `Reduce` to get the points.

```
sol = Solve[RegionMember[ri, {x, y}]]
{x, y} /. sol // N
```

> `{{2.95674, 3.87023}, {3.20154, 4.60463}, {3.42285, 5.26855}}`